# Rails 3: How to control radio button selection via object's field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, radio-button

In order to have a default value of select box, say:

```
<select name="job[worker_id]" id="job_worker_id">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">Alex</option>
  <option value="2">Simon</option>
  <option value="3">Jessica</option>
</select>
```

I do the following in controller's "new" method:

```
@job.worker_id = 3
```

How can I do something similar with radio buttons ?

The problem is that each button has its own `id`. For example:

```
<input type="radio" value="2" name="job[money_received]" id="job_money_received_2">
<input type="radio" value="1" name="job[money_received]" id="job_money_received_1">
<input type="radio" value="0" name="job[money_received]" id="job_money_received_0">
```

I would like to write in controller:

```
@job.money_received = 1
```

and have the "Part" button selected.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you using a certain form helper to generate the html of the form tags?

Comment: Yes, I use `f.radio_button(...)` to generate the radio buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
 @job.money_received = "1"
```

Should work great with form like this:

```
<%= f.radio_button :money_recieved, "1" %>
<%= f.radio_button :money_recieved, "2" %>
<%= f.radio_button :money_recieved, "3" %>
```

Radio with value = "1" will be checked

Answer (score 1):

Try to use formtastic

https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic

```
<%= semantic_form_for @job, :url => jobs_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :worker_id,  :as => :select,  :collection => @workers %>
  <%= f.input :money_received,  :as => :radio,  :collection => @money_received %>
<% end %>
```

There will be no logic to think about. Don't waste your time on forms.

mw

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted to suggest, you might also want to take a look at https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form which is a bit more customizable than formtastic. I also think you should use the value option in formtastic/simple_form to set the default value. This would be overwritten by the post data if set.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll definitely consider using one of them in my next project. I just don't want to change all my forms now...